# Which on is better? php on iis or php on WAMP Server on windows server 2003(VDS)

Tags: php, mysql, iis, wampserver, windows-server-2003

I have a VDS(Virtual Dedicated Server) that Windows Server 2003 is installed on it. I want to use php and MySQL on my VDS. I have two options: 1-install wamp server as a web server or 2-install iis and then use php and MySQL on iis.
Which one do you suggest me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wamp is a great tool for development but it's not very secure and fast for production.

In my opinion, on Windows the best option is IIS, faster and more secure.

You can easily find some tests by searching on Internet :
https://groups.drupal.org/node/234373

Answer (score 1):

I recommand wamp, more stable and efficient.